# Issue sending data from my form to SQL database

Tags: php, sql

I am having some kind of issue with the last variable `$type`. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. It is properly displaying everything but it will not write it back to the database when I save. If I remove any reference to the variable "$type" then my form writes to the database just fine. Below are the pieces of code that are relevant to my problem.

```
if(isset($_POST['update-project']))
{
   $flag=0;
   if($flag==0)
   {
     $s_idsa    = implode(',', $_POST['staff']);
     $pp_id     = $pro_id;
     $pp_title  = $_POST['projectTite'];
     $pc_id     = $_POST['client'];
     $ps_ids    = $s_idsa;
     $pp_desc   = $_POST['description'];
     $p_budget  = $_POST['budget'];
     $p_status  = $_POST['status'];
     $p_archive = $_POST['archive'];
     $ps_time   = $_POST['startTime'];
     $pe_time   = $_POST['endTime'];
     $type      = $_POST['type'];

     $sql_up = "UPDATE `projects` SET `c_id`='$pc_id', `s_ids`='$ps_ids', `project_title`='$pp_title', `project_desc`='$pp_desc', `budget`='$p_budget',    `status`='$p_status', `archive`='$p_archive', `start_time`='$ps_time',    `end_time`='$pe_time','proj_type'='$type' WHERE `p_id`='$pp_id'";


if ($connect->query($sql_up) === TRUE)
                {
header("Location:projects.php?message=success");
                }
                else
                {
header("Location:projects.php?message=fail");
                }
$connect->close(); 


     <div class="form-group">
        <select class="ui dropdown form-control" name="type" id="hidden" required>
            <option value="">Select a Project Type</option>
            <option value="1"<?php if($proj_type == 1){ ?> selected <?php } ?>>Without Invoicing</option>
            <option value="2"<?php if($proj_type == 2){ ?> selected <?php } ?>>With Invoicing</option>
        </select>
     </div>
```

Comment: You are not properly escaping your query, this can lead to SQL injection. Please look into prepared/parameterized queries http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php. Also, I see nothing regarding an actual database object/connection... Is there more code that is not displayed here?

Comment: Thank you for your willingness to help. I am very new to php so forgive me for my ignorance. There is more code in the file but I have narrowed it down to something wrong with this variable. If I remove "$type =$_POST['type'];" and "'proj_type'='$type'" and the entire .form-group, then everything works like it should.

Comment: I just updated the code above to show where the query closes.

Comment: What exactly is the content of $type. I know what we think it is, but it might be something different. Do a var_dump to know for sure

Comment: check your database field type, might be its only allowing `int`

Comment: Just like @SagarPPanchal suggested, `echo` out your query, and run it as pure SQL in adminer (or in your terminal) and check if there is an SQL error.

Comment: var_dump = string(1)"1"

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
"'proj_type'='$type'" //needs backticks instead of single quotes. doh.
```